# angular-php: form data is empty in php

Tags: php, angularjs

I am using angular as frontend and php as backend here is the code of angular.

```
$scope.processForm = function($scope.formData) {
    console.log($scope.formData);
    $http({
        method  : 'POST',
        url     : 'process.php',
        data    : {'data': $scope.formData,'uid':uid}, // no need to use $.param, even never see it in angular
        headers : { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }  
    })
```

here is the **process.php**

```
$postContent= file_get_contents("php://input"); 
$req= json_decode($postContent); 
$formData= $req->formData; 
$uid= $req->uid;
```

problem is $formData is empty in php. however $uid is showing value.

in form i have two entry email and password but i don't know how can i use that in php because formdata is empty.

I checked in firebug and found data is posting.

```
{"formData":{"password":"ff","cpassword":"errgreg"},"uid":"75"}:""
```

But nothing is coming response tab of firebug.

Comment: `headers : { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }` <- do you actually know what this does?

Comment: Use `$formData= $req->data;` instead of `$formData= $req->formData;` as the parameter is `data` not `formData`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you call your function with something like `ng-submit="processForm(formData)"` then this is all you actually need

```
$scope.processForm = function(formData) {
  $http.post('process.php', {
    formData: formData, // note the key is "formData", not "data"
    uid: uid // no idea where uid comes from
  });
};
```

---

Where you have

```
$scope.processForm = function($scope.formData) {
```

isn't even valid JavaScript. You cannot use object dot notation in function argument names. That should have been throwing an error in your console.

---

You also appeared to be incorrectly setting your request content-type. You are sending JSON, not `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` formatted data. Angular's default POST content-type (`application/json`) is sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this..

```
$json='{"formData":{"password":"ff","cpassword":"errgreg"},"uid":"75"}';
$req= json_decode($json); 
$formData= $req->formData; 
$uid= $req->uid;
$password = $req->formData->password;
$cpassword = $req->formData->cpassword;
```

OR convert into array using `json_decode()` with second argument as `true`.

```
$json='{"formData":{"password":"ff","cpassword":"errgreg"},"uid":"75"}';
$req= json_decode($json,true);//converts into array format 
$formData= $req['formData']; 
//print_r($formData);
echo $formData['password'];
```

Comment: How does this help OP get data from the client-side?